# How to do Active Directory authentication in Razor (cshtml)

Tags: authentication, razor, active-directory, ldap

I am doing a simple website with Razor. Currently, I have database-based authentication that works, as follows:

In _AppStart.chtml:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("db_connection",
       "users", "id", "username", true);
```

In login.cshtml page:

```
    username = Request["username"];
    password = Request["password"];

    if (WebSecurity.Login(username, password, true))
    {
        Response.Redirect("/admin");
    }
    else
    {
        errorMessage = "Login was not successful.";
    }
```

In protected CSHTML pages, I have the following at the top of a page:

```
if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Response.Redirect("/login.cshtml");
}
```

Everything is pretty simple and works well. Now I would like to add authentication with AD. I don't know how to do it.

I came from the Java world with many years of experience. For this simple website, I do not need MVC architecture. I need simple things similar to the above  (if possible). I need to do authentication just within the login.cshtml file. I googled a lot and am unable to find a tutorial (so that I can copy and paste) for what I need.

Any pointers or help is really appreciated!

Thanks and Regards

**Update: This application sits on the internal network.**

**Update 2: Here is the code I have after successfully implemented X3074861X's code**

```
if (IsPost)
{
    username = Request["username"];
    password = Request["password"];
    var domain = "domain";
    var host = "host";
    var port = "389";

    LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(host + ":" + port);
    try
    {
        // authenticate the username and password
        using (ldapConnection)
        {
            // pass in the network creds, and the domain.
            var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
            // if we're using unsecured port 389, set to false. If using port 636, set this to true.
            ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = false;
            // since this is an internal application, just accept the certificate either way
            ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };
            // to force NTLM\Kerberos use AuthType.Negotiate, for non-TLS and unsecured, just use AuthType.Basic
            ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
            // this is where the authentication occurs
            ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);

            //check local database to make sure the user is one of we allowed
            if (WebSecurity.Login(username, "fixed-password, just to check whether someone is on the list of allowed people", true))
            {
                Response.Redirect("/admin");
            }
            else
            {
                errorMessage = "Login was not successful.";
            }
        }
    }

    catch (LdapException exception)
    {
        //Authentication failed, exception will dictate why
        errorMessage = "Login was not successful.";
    }
```

Some explanation. I dont have control over the AD and so I can only authenticate users against it. I still have a little local database that indicates who can access the app. Everyone with access to the app has the same rights.

**Thanks and credit goes to X3074861X.**

Comment: Is this an internal application, or do you have to call out to an Active Directory server outside of your network?

Comment: Yes. It is an internal application. Thanks so much for chiming in!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is an internal application, and you're looking for something simple, I would consider writing a single class to do the Active Directory authentication. You're going to need a couple things though, in order for this to work :

- A reference to `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` in your project.
- The IP or DNS name of your Active Directory server. We'll call it `host` in the code below.
- The port it's running on (LDAPS will be port 636, basic LDAP will be port 389). We'll call it `port` in the code below.
- The Domain to which your users belong. We'll call it `domain` in the code below.

Now that you have that, you can wire this up to check the credentials from the request against your AD instance. I would try something like this :

```
// the username and password to authenticate
username = Request["username"];
password = Request["password"];

// define your connection
LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection("host:port");

try
{
      // authenticate the username and password
      using (ldapConnection)
      {
          // pass in the network creds, and the domain.
          var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

          // if we're using unsecured port 389, set to false. If using port 636, set this to true.
          ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = false;

          // since this is an internal application, just accept the certificate either way
          ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };

          // to force NTLM\Kerberos use AuthType.Negotiate, for non-TLS and unsecured, just use AuthType.Basic
          ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;

          // authenticate the user
          ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
      }
      catch (LdapException ldapException)
      {
          //Authentication failed, exception will dictate why
      }
}
```

Also, in the same way you'd communicate an authorization issue before, the `ldapException` can tell you why the call failed. If you want to display custom messaging, I would check the `LdapException.ErrorCode` property, and maybe create a case statement of return messages based on the [error codes](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=LDAP_Error_Codes).

Or, you could just output `LdapException.Message` directly to the page - either way, that will at least dictate to the user why their login didn't work.

Comment: X3074861X: thanks for the sample. I will give it a try and get back to you. Again, thanks!!!

Comment: X3074861X: it works very well. Thanks sooooooo much for crystal-clear code and explanation!!!!  "this is where the authorization occurs" should be "authenticate"?

Comment: @curious1 Cool man, glad I could help! As for the code comment, I wanted to illustrate that the `.Bind` is what actually performs the login against Active Directory, but I do see your point - I'll update accordingly.